# Calculate percent changes in contiguous ranges in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to calculate price percent change in contiguous ranges. For example if price start moving up or down and I have sequence of decreasing or increasing values I need to grab first and last value of that sequence and calculate the change.

I'm using window lag function to calculate direction, my problem- I can't generate unique RANK for the sequences to calculate percent changes.
I tired combination of RANK, ROW_NUMBER, etc. with no luck.

Here's my query

```
WITH partitioned AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    lag(price, 1) over(ORDER BY time) AS lag_price

  FROM prices 
),
sequenced AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    CASE 
      WHEN price > lag_price THEN 'up'
      WHEN price < lag_price THEN 'down'
      ELSE 'equal'
    END
     AS direction
  FROM partitioned

),
ranked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    -- Here's is the problem
    -- I need to calculate unique rnk value for specific sequence
    DENSE_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY direction ORDER BY time) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY time DESC) AS rnk
    -- DENSE_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY seq ORDER BY time),
    -- ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY seq, time DESC),
    -- ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY seq),
    -- RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY seq)

  FROM sequenced
),
changed AS (
  SELECT *,
    FIRST_VALUE(price) OVER(PARTITION BY rnk ) first_price,
    LAST_VALUE(price) OVER(PARTITION BY rnk ) last_price,
    (LAST_VALUE(price) OVER(PARTITION BY rnk ) / FIRST_VALUE(price) OVER(PARTITION BY rnk ) - 1) * 100 AS percent_change
    FROM ranked

)
SELECT
    *
FROM changed
ORDER BY time DESC;
```

and [SQLFiddle with sample data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fd248/3)

[image]

Comment: Sample data and desired results *as text tables in the question* would really help clarify what you want to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff There's a link to SQL Fiddle at the bottom of the post with sample data

Comment: . . It does not show what *results* you want.  I really can't apply your explanation to the data -- and I'm pretty good at understanding data problems.

Comment: If you want to find [local maximum and minimum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima) than it could be something like `case when lag(price) over (order by time) > price and lead(price) over (order by time) > price then 'minimum' when lag(price) over (order by time) < price and lead(price) over (order by time) < price then 'maximum' else 'plain' end` There is the question how to deal with equal values of `lag`, `current` and `lead`...

Comment: Here's screenshot https://paste.pics/c1265f5f1fab03ccd1ca894226e11706

I need to generate the uniq rank for contiguous direction sequence, so I can calculate percent change for that sequence. If sequence has more than one rows it should show percent_diff (based on first and last value). If it's has only one orphan row, percent_change is 0 (because first and last row is the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone interested here's solution, form another forum:

```
  with ct1 as /* detecting direction: up, down, equal */
    (
      select
          price, time,
          case 
            when lag(price) over (order by time) < price then 'down'
            when lag(price) over (order by time) > price then 'up'
            else 'equal' 
          end as dir
      from
          prices
    )
    , ct2 as /* setting reset points */
    (
      select
          price, time,  dir,
          case 
              when coalesce(lag(dir) over (order by time), 'none') <> dir
              then 1 else 0
          end as rst
      from
          ct1
    )
    , ct3 as /* making groups */
    (
      select
          price, time, dir,
          sum(rst) over (order by time) as grp
      from
          ct2
    )
    select /* calculates min, max price per group */
        price, time, dir,
        min(price) over (partition by grp) as min_price,
        max(price) over (partition by grp) as max_price
    from
        ct3
    order by
        time desc;
```